# In ckeditör automatically when the page loads I want to run any command

Tags: dialog, command, ckeditor

In ckeditör automatically when the page loads I want to run any command. (for example image or smiley dialog window or italic command.)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
   //ckeditor image dialog open or bold command...
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKeditor Auto open Dialog window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923636/ckeditor-auto-open-dialog-window)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script> 
      CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ){
        CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(129);
      });
</script>
```

in the toolbar of your image button onclick event command number.